# C++ - Template function that can return different types?

Tags: c++, templates, template-function

I'm working on a section of code that allows the user to search by different types (`double`/`string`/`date`(custom class)). This involves a method called `readInSearchCriteria()` that I have tried to set as a template. I have done some research into template functions and here is what I have so far:

```
//template function to process different datatypes
template <typename T> UserInterface::readInSearchCriteria() const {
    //template instance to hold data input from keyboard
    T t;
    //prompt user to enter a value
    cout << "\n ENTER SEARCH CRITERIA: ";
    //read-in value assigned to template variable
    cin >> t;

    //return initialised template variable
    return t;
}
```

I have called this at one point in the program to process a `double` like so:

```
double amount = theUI_.readInSearchCriteria<double>(); //works absolutely fine
```

However, when I tried to call it on a `string`, I was given the following error by the compiler:

> no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "std::basic_string, std::allocator>"

Would anyone be able to offer me any advice on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Where is your return type in that code? Are you missing a `T`?

Comment: where is the return value? shouldn't it be type T

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in your function declaration: you're not specifying a return type, so the compiler is defaulting to `int`.

You need to add `T` as the return type:

```
template <typename T>
T UserInterface::readInSearchCriteria() const {
    ...
    return T
}
```

Comment: This clears everything up, very logical now I think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The method `readInSearchCriteria` doesn't have a return type. You have to specify the return type for a function, here it is implicit `int` because you haven't specified one.

```
template <typename T> T UserInterface::readInSearchCriteria() const;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, really helped!